# Using different timezone for jackson serialization per user tenant

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, timezone, multi-tenant

### Problem

If have Pojo with:

```
@JsonFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ") // Note the 'Z' for timezone
Instant date;
```

I want the serialized JSON be presented in different timezone based on `TimeZoneAwareLocaleContext`

### Description

I have multi-tenan Spring (boot) MVC application where each tenant defines timezone in which she would like to get her data.

I understand I can register `TimeZoneAwareLocaleContext` into `LocaleContext` and how to do it but I struggle to understand how (if even possible) force Jackson to serialize dates with respect to the LocalContext time-zone.

I also considered using custom tenant-aware Jackson serializer but it feels there might already be an out of box solution which I'm overlooking.